# How do I scale a vector image before using it as a layer in the output image

Tags: php, vector, svg, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am constructing an image using some raster and some vector files and I'm outputting it to a png. Is there a way for me to prescale one of these vectors before i produce the png?

For example if the vector is huge, it would be a problem producing the raster since if i later scale down the raster, the vector (no longer a vector) will look distorted. Thus far im using imagemagic  to produce the png.

Any ideas on how i can prescale the vectors while the still have vector scaling capabilites before i write my png?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-scale the SVG yourself by manipulating its DOM. By varying the `viewBox`, `width` and `height` attributes of the <svg> element, you can effectively scale the entire image.

There's an example in the SVG 1.1 Recommendation, at: [7.7 The ‘viewBox’ attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute).